# keep_alive options for boost tcp acceptor and boost tcp socket

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp, boost-asio

I have few questions, all related to `keep_alive`.

- What is the difference between [`basic_socket_acceptor::keep_alive`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/keep_alive.html) and [`basic_stream_socket::keep_alive`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/keep_alive.html)? When to use which?
- Do we need to use any kind of `keep_alive` for [`ip::tcp::acceptor`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/acceptor.html)? It doesn't make sense to me, as there is *no* connection as such for acceptor but there is a `keep_alive` *option* for it as well, hence the confusion.
- If `keep_alive` is set, then what is the behaviour of Boost Asio when it detects broken connection? How/when does it notify the user-code? Does it throw exception? If so, which exception? I don't see any such details in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the difference between basic_socket_acceptor::keep_alive and
>   basic_stream_socket::keep_alive? When to use which?

Both are same. In the documentation, it appears under `basic_socket_acceptor` and `basic_stream_socket` because both are derived from `socket_base` in which `keepalive` option is actually visible (it's a typedef).

As per the example in the documentation, you will always use it like:

```
boost::asio::socket_base::keep_alive option(true);
socket.set_option(option);
```

> Do we need to use any kind of keep_alive for ip::tcp::acceptor?

No you don't have to and you cannot. `set_option` anyways can be called only on a socket object (I believe only after socket is `opened`).

> If keep_alive is set, then what is the behaviour of Boost Asio when it
>   detects broken connection?

This is dependent on the platform. On `linux` you would be getting `broken pipe` error or `EPOLLERR`/`EPOLLHUP` when keep_alive probe fails.

**UPDATE** (from my comment below):

This failure is not propagated to the user code. So, either probably you need to implement an application level ping or use the timeout socket option.

Comment: *"On linux you would be getting broken pipe error or EPOLLERR/EPOLLHUP when keep_alive probe fails."*. How would **I** (i.e the user-code) get anything if I dont *explicitly* send any keepalive packets? I believe after setting `keep_alive` option, the underlying library sends such packets to the clients and I probably dont know when and how frequently it does so. Whatever be the answers to these questions, my only concern is *how* exactly does it notify the user when it sees a *broken pipe*? Do I need to set any callback which the library would call?

Comment: Oh..ok. Actually the sending and receiving of the keep alive probes is done by the OS and controlled by the `sysctl` parameters in linux. So, even if you set keepalive option on the socket in your code, it doesn't mean that the OS will send the probes. You need to explicitly enable it via `procfs` or `sysctl` and while you are at it, you can even adjust the timer for sending the keepalive probes.

Comment: " my only concern is how exactly does it notify the user when it sees a broken pipe? Do I need to set any callback which the library would call?  "  You are correct, I didn't go through the complete implementation. This failure is not propagated to the user code.  So, either probably you need to implement an application level ping or use the `timeout` socket option.

Comment: @Nawaz You can receive the asynchronous SIGPIPE signal. Boost Asio has `signal_set` you can use for this. How you correlate the signal to a specific socket is your challenge, but at least this gives you connection drop alerts.

Comment: @sehe: I think that is a good start. Thanks. I've one more query: the server starts listening by calling `acceptor::listen()` followed by `acceptor::async_accept()` and now if there is no activity for few days, do I need to do something to ensure that "listen/async_accept" would still work and they're not dead due to inactivity (I dont even know if the phrases like *dead* are even applicable here)?

Comment: @Nawaz  "now if there is no activity for few days, do I need to do something to ensure that "listen/async_accept"" Are you speaking in context to keepalive ? If yes, then keepalive probes are only applicable to established connections, not before that.

Comment: @Arunmu: You didn't understand my question. I think you don't understand what `listen()` and `accept()` are.

Comment: @Nawaz I expected you to expand on your question instead of assuming what I know or don't.

Comment: @Arunmu: Yes. Once I call `listen()` followed by `accept()`. It is prepared to accept new connections. Right? Now my question is: if there is a very long inactivity on the "listening" socket (means there is no new connection for a very long time, say days or months), but after a long period of inactivity, certain clients want to connect to the server. Will the `accept` function work by its own? Or I should do something else, to ensure that it works? Like re-calling `listen` and `accept` periodically, to ensure that these calls are not dead/forgotten by the underlying machinery?

Comment: @Nawaz Thanks. I will stick to `asio::async_*` version of `accept` to answer it.  No, you do not have to call `listen` or `accept` again. `asio` calls `listen` on the underlying socket when you construct the `acceptor`. Now, assuming that you have already called `async_accept` on the `acceptor` with a callback handler ( NOTE: the handler should call `async_accept` again for it to accept other incoming connections on the listen queue) AND `io_service` always has some work to do i.e you have set `asio::work` object then you do not have to worry about it. The listening `file descriptor` .....

Comment: .... would always be registered to `epoll` waitlist maintained by the kernel. You can see  this example http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp

Comment: Yes. I meant the boost version of `listen` and `accept` (I just avoided the longer names to save some  space). And yes, I've seen the examples. I've even written a  HTTP server, and deployed it to the production. It is working great. Now I'm working on its stability, which is why I'm asking these questions thinking about the corner-cases, which require very intimate knowledge of the API and the underlying stuffs. Unfortunately, I've not come across any examples (and comments therein) and documentation which clarify by doubts.

Comment: I see what you are saying. You can look at some implementation which are using asio in production for eg: https://github.com/ripple/rippled . Anyways, asio does not abstract away the details that much. It should behave exactly (almost) like a hand written `epoll` based event loop unless you have some complicated logic where you do `io_service::stop` and `io_service::reset` kind of stuffs in your code.

Comment: As for my experience with `asio`, I do play around with its code base a  lot mostly for fun, but have never used it to deploy it on production. Things get bit complicated once you start using `strand` to control the handler execution sequence and other custom `io_object` and services. AFAIK, there are not many (or at all) blogs or documentations that goes into the details of what ASIO does, but you can always go through the source code. You will get comfortable with it once you understand the basic pattern followed by the author.

Comment: @sehe: I used SIGPIPE and `keep_alive` option on the new tcp socket, but still I dont get `SIGPIPE` signal. Looks like something is missing.

Comment: Looks like assumptions were made. FTR I have never checked the docs for SO_KEEPALIVE. http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/4.7.shtml

Comment: @sehe: I used `::setsockopt` as suggested [here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/#setsockopt) to override the system-wide values of *probes*, *intvl* and *time*,  to `2`, `2`, `4` respectively for POC purpose. But it didn't work. My handler doesn't get invoked. I'm using Boost *signals_set* to register the signals. I also ensured `SIGPIPE` is not blocked in any of my threads.

Comment: @Nawaz I don't know much about SO_KEEPALIVE. For what I know SIGPIPE might be completely unused. Signal handlers/masks can be per-thread. The linked article seems to suggest keepalive time cannot (portably) be controlled etc.

Comment: You don't need to monkey with signals. Presumably, you are trying to read from the connection. If the connection breaks, that will no longer possible and your read attempt will fail. If it was a blocking read, it will unblock. If it was some kind of async read, it will complete with an error.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The problem would be with the servers where clients (mobile clients esp) maintain persistent connection with the server and it's the client which initiates the request. If the client just goes "off", the server side either needs to enable keepalive or design some application level liveness check per connection by doing an applicative ping periodically.

Comment: @Arunmu Right, but it doesn't need to monkey with signals. Once it does what you said, then its read will complete when/if the connection breaks. And that check will ensure the connection breaks if the other side goes away.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I've implemented SSE using Boost.Asio. Currently the server accepts the new *sse*  connections, and maintains a map for them, for later use. However, I need to implement some cleanup strategy, otherwise the map will grow indefinitely. The approach I'm currently implemented is this: the server sends some *ping* message  to all the clients at an interval of `30` seconds or so, if the send fails with `Broken Pipe`, I remove the corresponding connection from the map. Now I'm not sure if that is the right approach. What do you suggest? .... [continued]

Comment: [continued] .... Instead of my own implementation of *ping* message, I thought of using Boost keep_alive functionality, and thought it will notify me the connections which have broken pipe so that I could remove them from the map. That is why I created this topic. So far I'm *not* able to use it. I'm still using *ping* approach.

Comment: @sehe `SO_KEEPALIVE` notifies thread writing to the socket via a `SIGPIPE` signal, but Asio explicitly disables receiving `SIGPIPE` on write operations.  Consequently, the underlying system call will return with the relevant error.

Comment: @TannerSansbury: If `SIGPIPE` is disabled on *write*, how then would the app know that the connection is broken? I have the same (and related) doubts earlier in this comment section. It would be helpful for me if you go through them.

Comment: @Nawaz The Asio write operation will fail with an error.

Comment: @TannerSansbury: So until I write, I wont get notified, even though `keep_alive` has detected broken pipe much before?

Comment: @Nawaz Correct.  When a half-open connection occurs, read operations will detect the connection state much faster than write operations.  The keep-alive options allows write operations to detect the failure quicker.  The keep-alive option obviates having to implement a probe with timeout in the application protocol; however, the application will still need to perform an I/O operation to detect the connection state.

Comment: @Nawaz No, you will know before you write. Your *read* will fail. You are trying to read from the connection right? If not, how would you know if the client sent you a command?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: No. I'm not reading. I've implemented [SSE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events). So when the connection is made, (i.e when the server accepts a request), it stores the connection in a map so that in future it can *push* messages to the client. It is only *write* which I'm doing after I store in the map!

Comment: @Nawaz In an active close, the first write operation will fail; in a passive close, some write operations may succeed before a failure; in a half-open connection (e.g. network cable unplugged), the write operations will succeed until the maximum retransmission threshold has been breached (see `tcp_retries1 ` and `tcp_retries2`, but defaults to 13-30mins~).  If you are not interested in the application responsiveness of the remote peer, perhaps using a read on the sockets to observe a change in the connection state is easier than a keepalive and ping message?

Comment: @TannerSansbury The read won't observe anything if he doesn't have a keepalive or a ping message. No packets will be sent or received, and that is just fine.

Comment: @David I poorly expressed my sentiment.  I meant to imply that keep-alive and a single longstanding read operation may be simpler than a periodic probe in the application protocol.  Although `SO_KEEPALIVE` is documented to signaling the write thread, the state change may be observable on read operations for some systems.

Comment: @TannerSansbury It had better be observable on read operations on every system. The read is no longer pending, that *must* be observable.

Comment: I dont think *read* for my case even makes sense. As I've mentioned earlier, I've implemented SSE, which is used to *push* messages to the clients. *push* means I do only *write* operations.

Comment: @Nawaz I assume what TannerSansbury wanted to say is, you should periodically do a `read` on the nonblocking socket. If it returns `EWOULDBLOCK`, that means the connection is open. Else, if the connection is closed at the other end, it would return `eof`. In this case you can probably save yourself from implementing the ping-pong code. This probably needs to be done in safe way, if you end up using system API's directly.

Comment: @Arunmu: As I mentioned it is `SSE`, which only supports one-way communication (half-duplex), which is : *server* to *client*. *read* from such connection at server does not make sense and is *semantically* wrong. Seems we are not on the same page, hence the confusion!

Comment: @Nawaz Hmm..ok. I understand.

Answer (score 2):

The [`basic_socket_acceptor::keep_alive`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/keep_alive.html) and [`basic_stream_socket::keep_alive`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/keep_alive.html) are the same.  The documentation notes that they are both inherited from the [`socket_base`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/socket_base.html) class which defines the [`socket_base::keep_alive`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/socket_base/keep_alive.html) option.

> **`basic_stream_socket::keep_alive`**
>
> *Inherited from socket_base.*
>
> Socket option to send keep-alives.

While keep-alive on the listening socket is not directly useful for the listening socket, on some systems the newly accepted socket inherits some socket options from the listening socket.  The inherited socket options are generally options that would affect the TCP three-way handshake that must complete before `accept()` returns, such as `SO_KEEPALIVE`.  Consequently, Asio supports setting the keep-alive option on an acceptor; however, Asio does not copy socket options to the new socket.

The keep-alive feature allows for *write* operations to be notified that a connection is broken as determined by the keep-alive mechanism<sup>1</sup>.   Hence, when the keep-alive probe fails, the next Asio write operation on the socket will fail<sup>2</sup>, passing the `error_code` to the application in the same way other error codes are provided.  One should consult the operating system's documentation to determine the expected error code from the write operation:

- On Windows, [`WSASend()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742203(v=vs.85).aspx) is documented as returning `WSAENETRESET` (`boost::asio::error:: connection_reset`)
- On Linux, the error will vary based on how the keep-alive probe fails.  If no responses occur, then `ETIMEOUT` (`boost::asio::error::timed_out`) will occur.  If an ICMP error is returned in response to a keep-alive probe, then the relevant ICMP error will be returned instead.  For example, one could observe `EHOSTUNREACH` (`boost::asio::error::host_unreachable`) being returned

---

<sup>1. See 4.2.3.6 on the *Requirements for Internet Hosts—Communication Layers* specified in [RFC 1122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1122.txt)

 2. `SO_KEEPALIVE` notifies thread writing to the socket via a `SIGPIPE` signal, but Asio explicitly disables receiving `SIGPIPE` on write operations. Consequently, the underlying system call will return with the relevant error</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the platform you are running on. On linux if you do exactly the following,

```
boost::asio::socket_base::keep_alive option(true);
socket.set_option(option);
```

then you are basically protected from minor network interruptions that can occur and cause a read or write error on the socket. If you set `keep_alive` to true on the socket pointer then there are couple of certain ways to detect an error on the socket you are reading/writing on:

- Firstly, you can detect a socket error by implementing a ping pong mechanism of sending a health packet in intervals between the peers.
- Or, you can also detect an error when you are returned with a `boost::asio::error::eof` error from the socket which basically means that the peer has closed the connection. Note that a read on the socket can still return an `boost::asio::error::eof` error if the connection is closed by the peer.